# How can I control the order on what tick methods are executed across components?

Tags: aframe, webvr, webxr

I have multiple components that define a `tick` method and I need to control the execution order. With the following components:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('component-a', {    
  tick: function () { console.log('ComponentA'); }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('component-b', {    
  tick: function () { console.log('ComponentB'); }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('component-c', {    
  tick: function () { console.log('ComponentC'); }
});
```

And the following entity:

```
<a-entity component-a component-b component-c></a-entity>
```

I want to guarantee the following tick order: component-a, component-b, component-c

Answer (score 2):

A-Frame does not have a built-in way to define tick execution order. Ticks will execute in the order in what components are initialized. One can easily control the execution by having a `manager component` that calls the components methods in the desired order:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('manager', {    
  tick: function () {
    const el = this.el;
    el.components['component-a'].print();
    el.components['component-b'].print();
    el.components['component-c'].print();
  }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('component-a', {    
  print: function () { console.log('ComponentA'); }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('component-b', {    
  print: function () { console.log('ComponentB'); }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('component-c', {    
  print: function () { console.log('ComponentC'); }
});
```

On the following entity:

```
<a-entity manager component-a component-b component-c>
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a [system](https://aframe.io/docs/master/core/systems.html) exclusively for such managing, or is it an overkill ?